# UIKitCore location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

I am attempting to create an iOS app from an Xcode template.

```
Xcode->File->New Project->App
```

I made no changes to the generated code.  However, when I attempt to compile the app, I get the error "Module UIKitCore not found".

When I attempt to add the framework from:

```
General->Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content (iOS 14.3)
```

UIKitCore is not an option.  Furthermore, UIKitCore is not discussed in any of the Apple documents.

Where can I find the framework (or module) "UIKitCore"?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on but sounds like UIKitCore is not a public library. When your xcode starts up, does it ask to install additional components? Maybe a reinstallation would help.

Comment: Oddly, I can compile older apps that I've created.  I just cannot create new apps.  I may have to try to re-install.  Seems really bizarre that Apple has introduced a dependency on a non-existent framework.  Like I said, there is not one mention of UIKitCore in Apple documentation.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that Apple has officially dropped support for Objective-c.  I believe UIKitCore is a swift framework.   Since there is no compatibility between objective-c and swift frameworks objective-c applications will no longer compile.

Comment: Where did you hear of Apple dropping Obj C support? Are you just assuming, as I highly doubt that.

Comment: Apple has stopped maintaining multiple versions of core libraries in both Objective-C and Swift.  RealityKit, for example, is a Swift only framework which is not compatible with Objective-C. If you want to use RealityKit, for example, your application must be a Swift application.  Yep.  Apple has dropped support for Objective-C.

Comment: I installed Xcode version 12.3 on a total of 3 machines now.  This issue persists across 3 different machines now.  Swift works, objective-c does not work.  Moving onto swift now, goodbye objective-c.

Comment: Dang thats a shame ey coz Objective C is awesomely 'easy'. Good luck with swift, it's way better once you get a hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

UIKitCore is a Swift framework.
Swift frameworks are not compatible with Objective-c applications.
To resolve this issue you will need re-create the app as a Swift only application.